# Harmonic average over slices of three-dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a three-dimensional array, I want to compute both the arithmetic and harmonic average over two-dimensional slices.

This can easily be done using numpy's arithmetic average:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5*3*3).reshape(5,3,3)
np.mean(a,axis=(1,2))
```

For the harmonic average, I have to slice the three-dimensional array myself.
I can do so along the first (0th) axis, for example:

```
from scipy import stats
b = a.reshape(np.shape(a)[0], -1)
stats.hmean(b,axis=1)
```

How do I have to reshape/slice my three-dimensional array to compute the average perpendicular to the other axes (that is, average over axes 0 and 2 or over axes 0 and 1)?

To clarify, the corresponding arithmetic averages are simply given by:

```
np.mean(a,axis=(0,2))
np.mean(a,axis=(0,1))
```

Comment: why don't you just stick with numpy and do this `1/np.mean(1/a, axis=(1,2))` for harmonic means? Correct me if I am wrong in understanding your problem

Comment: Great! Yes, you are right. I was thinking so much about slicing that I overlooked this neat numpy solution. That solves my problem (in particular since a similar trick is available for the geometric mean). Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help! cheers!

Comment: For other types of problems, I would still be interested in how to slice the 3D array, so that the middle axis is preserved. This problem, however, is solved by your nice and simple solution. Do you want to post it, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just stick to numpy and adapt your code to compute harmonic mean as follows-

```py
1/np.mean(1/a, axis=(0,2))
1/np.mean(1/a, axis=(0,1))
```

Comment: Thanks again! Your quick answer was a great help to me. Just for completeness, I add that I use `1/np.mean(1/a, axis=(0,2))` for averaging perpendicular to the middle axis and `1/np.mean(1/a, axis=(0,1))` for averaging perpendicular to the last axis.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I just meant to give an idea cause the slice axis can be arbitrary as required.

Comment: Yes, well said. It is a very versatile answer. Just in case that someone is interested in the geometric mean, the analogous trick is `np.exp(np.mean(np.log(a),axis=(0,2)))` assuming that all entries of `a` are positive.